Marking Account with green/ orange/ red flags relative to "Do not contact review date"
I have an Account Object Manager Fields & Relationships query:
I would like to please mark "Do Not Contact review date" (Field name: Do_not_contact_review_date__c) with:
A green flag if "Do Not Contact Review date" isn't populated (only possible if Contact [Field name:
contact_do_not_contact__c] is selected from "Contact/ Do Not Contact" picklist field).
An orange flag if "Do Not Contact Review date" is <= 14 days away from today's date (whatever today's date is at the time the Account is viewed).
A red flag if "Do Not Contact Review date" is > 14 days away from today's date.
Please may you advise which formula I should be using within the "Do not contact review date" formula editor?
Here are the flags I'm keen to use which are inbuilt options offered by Salesforce:
"/img/samples/flag_orange.gif",
"/img/samples/flag_red.gif",
"/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)


Why not use emojis, which are pretty much universal these days?

Thank you Renato Oliveira, I didn't know this was possible, that's a brilliant piece of advice!

Two options I can see for your need, though both will require you to create a separate formula (text output) field in addition to your Do_not_contact_review_date__c. You could call this new one "Do_not_contact_review_date_flag__c" or something like that.
Option 1:
Use emojis as Renato suggested in his comment. You can use a custom formula field with the IF() function. Something like:
>     IF( ISBLANK( Do_not_contact_review_date__c ), "",
>      IF( ( Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY() ) >= 14, "",
>      "" )
>     )

Option 2:
Use the IMAGE() function to display images instead of the emojis. Take the formula above and replace the  with IMAGE() function as described in this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_image.htm&type=5

Hi Miguel Diaz, thank you for your help. This is really clear. I've taken your Option 1 approach. However, when I Add a New Custom Data Type Text Field it says: "Error: Field Do_not_contact_review_date__c may not be used in this type of formula". I'm wondering, is there a way for this to please be resolved?

Sorted now. I tried to make a 'Text' field not a 'Formula - Text' field, thank you!

Good to hear, if the answer was helpful, you can mark is as an accepted answer (the checkmark) so others know that the answer is resolved at a glance
